# JavaScript error undefined object although object exist

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="full-details-box" name="full_details_box" id="full-details-box"></div>
        <hr />
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function show_3136(){
            document.full_details_box.style.display='block';
        }
        show_3136();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the error: window.document.full_details_box is undefined

I get the error for the line:

```
document.full_details_box.style.display='block';
```

But I do have a `<div>` element with the name `full_details_box`, so why the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `name` attribute for divs. It doesn't even exist. Use the id, and:

```
document.getElementById('full-details-box')...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_3136(){
     document.getElementById('full_details_box').style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access this element, use `getElementById`

```
function show_3136() {
    document.getElementById("full-details-box").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
document.getElementById("full-details-box").style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to your confusion - you may have been thinking about form fields
All of these will work on a form field (the first only if you wrap the field in form tags)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function showFormField(){
        document.forms[0].full_details_boxName.style.display='block';
        // or document.forms[0].elements["full_details_boxName"].style.display='block';
    }
    function showNamedField(){
        document.getElementsByName("full_details_boxName")[0].style.display='block';
    }
    function showFieldById(){
        document.getElementsById("full_details_boxID").style.display='block';
    }
    function showFieldByClassName(){ // does not work in all IE browsers
        document.getElementsByClassName("full_details_boxCLASS")[0].style.display='block';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input class="full-details-boxCLASS" name="full_details_boxName" id="full-details-boxID"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

for a DIV you will use ID or CLASS, but not name

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="full-details-box">
    Just some test content
</div>
<hr />
```

CSS:

```
div#full-details-box { 
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
function show_3136(){
    document.getElementById("full-details-box").style.display = "block";
}
show_3136();
```

For a working example, [see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cu6dX/)